# Is it okay to use "adequate/inadequate", to describe the quality of a product?

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to determine the result of a product's quality test as being either 'adequate' or 'inadequate'? The Oxford dictionary defines adequate as: Satisfactory or acceptable in quality or quantity.

But is it okay to say that "the quality is adequate"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adequate / inadequate can be used to describe the quality of a product. Perhaps your example,'The quality is adequate' needs more context to see if it's the best wording.
'(The product) is of an adequate quality to be used in ...' is okay, as is Excellent, Good, Adequate etc. for a rating scale.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is from a product quality checklist, and the words are to be used at the and of a test item. There are two choices as the result of an assessment, (passed/failed). And I was wondering if 'passed/failed' could be replaced with (adequate/inadequate).

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. Passed/Failed refers more to the 'test', whereas Adequate/Inadequate to the 'quality of the product'.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid syntax and semantically sound, but it has the connotation of a veiled insult which "satisfactory" doesn't (at least not as strongly).

Comment: It could be used to indicate that a product is not very well made but is suitable for a specific purpose. For example a pair of overalls could be described in a review as being "of quite poor quality but adequate for one-off emergency use". If they were cheap enough I might buy them to carry in the car in case I needed to change a wheel.